# How do I get the range of a specific XML node in a string?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, serialization

Say I have an XML Document from which I want to extract the location of the heading content.

```xml
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Given the structure of the Document I want to find the string range of the heading such that:

```cs
Range range = GetHeadingRange(xmlString);
string heading = xmlString[range]; // heading should now be "Reminder"
// How do I aquire a range like this (or an (offset, length))
```

I have already tried the XmlSerializer but I cannot get any token location information from the serializer. Are there maybe any lower XmlClasses that allow access closer to the input string?

---

EDIT: I need to figure out the offset and length of the matching sequence. I do not need the actual heading value, because I want to be able to highlight this location in the original text, i dont actually care about the value.

Comment: Why exactly do you want that? Why not just parse the XML?

Comment: What is the type of your `range` variable?

Comment: I don't understand what the `GetHeadingRange` function is supposed to do?

Comment: no clue what you mean with `Range` in your question?!?

Comment: @RandRandom based on the usage it seems that it is `Range` type which is used for indexers like `"asdsad"[1..3]`.

Comment: @GuruStron - yeah, maybe - but why? `XmlSerializer` and deserialize the xml to an `public class Note` seems to be way more usefull, than trying to get startindex and endindex of that single node to construct a range object?!? - and OP already tried `XmlSerializer` but ditched the idea because it didn't provide index information (as OP said `but I cannot get any token location information`)

Comment: @RandRandom _" but why? "_ - that is exactly what I have asked first =)

Comment: just droping it here, without knowing your reason to get a range (start - end index of the node) it seems to make more sense - https://dotnetfiddle.net/uCZEdi

Comment: @DavidG The `GetHeadingRange` function is the blank part that I'm missing, the reason for my question. sorry, that i didnt specify this. I want to get the range of the heading value in the original

Comment: @GuruStron I do know how to deserialize the object, but I need to exactly preserve the original document wih comments and format and only replace the value of this single token. Reason is the framework that requires the position of a string token to create the new string document with modifications (also for JSON and other formats where I can easily extract location information)

Answer (score 1):

In general you should never parse XML with regexes but for this particular the easiest option would be:

```cs
var s = """
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
""";
var match = Regex.Match(s, @"<heading>(?<val>.+?)<\/heading>");
if (match.Success)
{
    var matchGroup = match.Groups["val"];
    Range range = matchGroup.Index..(matchGroup.Index + matchGroup.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(s[range]);
}
```

But it is quite a brittle approach and in general you should just parse the XML (see the other answer)

Comment: While this really is not what I want to do in my project, It seems I'm currently stuck with something unstable like this. I thought, like many parsers, the Xml parsers in .NET might have stored the Token information after lexing.

Comment: @MichaelChen it actually can store some - `XDocument.Parse(s, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace | LoadOptions.SetLineInfo)`  but it want be that useful, it stores 1) line number + position in line, not the index 2) it stores start of node (i.e. from `<heading>`) 3) it stores "end" info but does not expose it publicly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to parse the XML into an `XDocument` and traverse that tree. For example:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var heading = doc.Element("note") // Get note element
    .Element("heading") // Now get heading element
    .Value; // Finally extract the content of the heading element

// heading will contain "Reminder"
```

Comment: but, how does that have anything to do with `Range`? (not that I have a clue what OP is acutally meaning)

Comment: I assume that OP thinks they need to do this with string manipulation and `range` is an actual C# range to be passed in to find the substring. Obviously that isn't necessary so I presented this as an alternative (and better) answer.

Comment: Yeah, Guru had the same idea, didn't think about it thought OP wants to do something with to/from in the xml - but who calls the sender and recipient of a note range?!? so, yeah I was confused

Comment: Yeah, though not sure I would have given regex as an answer, it's almost certainly a terrible way to do that.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I can get the value like this, but I really need to be able to figure out the location of this exact element in the original string.